# ¿Cómo podría hacer que dos números se sumen de forma continua durante el trascurso del usuario en mi web?

Tags: javascript

Pregunta Editada: 
He hecho otro code empleando while pero literalmente explota la web, imagino que será por el mal uso del mismo, perdonadme pero es que soy nuevo en esto.

Objetivo:

> lo que busco es que se sumen de forma continua dos números durante el
> trascurso del usuario en mi web y cuando se termine la sesión, es
> decir, cuando el usuario salga de la web, dependiendo del valor de esa
> variable se le asigne un tag como usuario interesado o usuario
> miss-clicked.

Dejo por aquí el code que he creado:

```
 function b(){
        var suma = parseInt(0) + parseInt(1);
        var suma_3 = localStorage.setItem('suma',suma);
        if (suma > 0) {
            while (suma > 0) {
                var sumisa = suma++;
                var sumisa_2 = suma++;
                var sumisos = parseInt(sumisa) - parseInt(sumisa_2);
                console.log('yes');
                if (sumisos = 0) {      
            var suma_2 = localStorage.getItem('suma', suma);
            var suma_recursiva = parseInt(suma_2) + 1;
                    console.log(suma_recursiva);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('xd');
        }
    }
   setInterval(b, 1000);
```

La explicación que yo le daría al code sería:
He creado una función a la cual le he seteado un intervalo para que cada 1000 ms (1s) se ejecute de nuevo la suma, tras haber probado me he dado cuenta de que funciona pero sigue realizando la misma suma de forma infinita, luego le he incorporado while. Usando while he restado los valores de la suma que hace de "suma++" para que no la haga de forma infinita y así se anule, quedando en loop la suma_2 que es la que me interesa.

Comment: ¿Has probado la función `setTimeout`?

Comment: Hola, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask],saludos.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys añadí esa parte del code que fue la que investigué pero claro, funcionó pero no cumple el propósito.

Comment: @Lobos Voy a revisar eso

Comment: @Lobos Acabo de hacer un breve code, pero tampoco cumple su funcionalidad ya que lo que quiero es que cada vez que un usuario acceda a mi web se active el temporizador y sume el valor de "1" a una variable que serán los segundos totales. Con setInterval se ejecuta el código bien y demás, pero la suma no es constante, es decir, que solamente se suma 0+1.
Edito la pregunta añadiendo ese código

Comment: Pues tienes mútiples opciones, dado que no requieres mucha precision para la aplicacion que comentas creo que el objeto Date es más que suficiente para ti. Capturas el instante de inicio con `var tiempoInicio = Date().getTime()` luego cuando algo pase haces `var tiempoFinal = Date().getTime()` y el tiempo transcurrido en milisegundos es simplemente `var tiempo = tiempoFinal - tiempoInicio`. Ese valor puedes enviarlo luego a tu servidor.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez voy a mirar eso

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez estoy probando pero tampoco cumple la funcionalidad, he pensado otra manera que sería mediante la suma de dos números continuamente durante el recorrido de la web y que cuando detecte que el usuario ya no está en la web se le asigne una variable que dependiendo del valor de esta será categorizada como miss-clicker o cliente interesado.
Voy a actualizar la pregunta con todo esto, de todas formas gracias

Comment: @galaixagalicia pero entonces no es un timer lo que necesitas como dices en tu pregunta, es básicamente un contador de clicks. Un timer es algo que mide tiempo, y ese nunca es tu objetivo.

Comment: ¿Que quieres medir exactamente? No queda nada claro. ¿Los clicks en la ventana del navegador? ¿Por otro lado, donde estas ejecutando tu código?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez He modificado la pregunta, a ver si así queda más claro, es que me acabo de dar cuenta de varias cosas

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Esencialmente sería como un contador de segundos que dependiendo del valor se le asigne un tag u otro